# Why are some keypresses not being captured during multi-key combinations?

Tags: java, keylistener

Is it a keyboard limitation problem?

I'm having an issue with some code I'm just playing around with. Imagine a top down space shooter. The issue I'm having is that, on my computer, when I press and hold the up and left arrows, I cannot shoot (Spacebar). Any other direction (up, down, left, right, up + right, right + down, left + down) works. I had a friend run the code on his computer and he found that all directions worked except up + right and right + down, but up + left worked fine for him. We both looked at the code and can't figure it out.   Could this be a hardware issue?

Basically, this is what I'm doing:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    boolean up, down, left, right, fire;

    // Main constructor
    public Test()
    {
        // listeners for user input
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                switch (e.getKeyCode())
                {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    {
                        up = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    {
                        left = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    {
                        right = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    {
                        down = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    {
                        fire = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                    {
                        // Exit
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                // Upon releasing key, stop direction
                switch(e.getKeyCode())
                {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    {
                        up = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    {
                        left = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    {
                        right = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    {
                        down = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            // create frame
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            test.setVisible(true);
            test.loop();
    }

    public void loop()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (up)
                    System.out.println("Moving UP.");
                if (left)
                    System.out.println("Moving LEFT.");
                if (right)
                    System.out.println("Moving RIGHT.");
                if (down)
                    System.out.println("Moving DOWN.");
                if (fire)
                {
                    System.out.println("FIRING.");
                    fire = false;
                }
            }
        });

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

This question was originally asked [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/529144/Game-Development/java/multiple-keys-pressed).

Comment: Is there a difference also in your OS or JVM version? Which keys fire in which OS does differ slightly. The best thing is probably to see what, if any, key events are being fired and go from there. Also, a library like Slick2D can help you abstract away these sorts of strange happenings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like a hardware limitation. You can try to check whether it behaves the same way in other programs, if yes, it's definitely a hardware issue.

Keyboards have these kinds of limitations, see [Rollover (key)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29).